# Finding the stability of $h(n) = 4^nu[-n-1]$ using z-transform

Tags: sequences-and-series, z-transform

I am trying to find the stability of $h(n) = 4^nu[-n-1]$ using Z-transform.

First I looked at Z=transform pairs but it resembles none of the Z-transform pairs.

$$a^nu[n]\Longleftrightarrow  \frac{1}{1-a \cdot z^{-1}}, \lvert z\rvert>\lvert a\rvert$$

$$-a^nu[-n-1]\Longleftrightarrow  \frac{1}{1-a\cdot z^{-1}}, \lvert z\rvert<\lvert a\rvert$$

Therefore, I will calculate Z-transform from the beginning:

$$\sum_{n= -\infty}^\infty 4^n\cdot u[-n-1] \cdot z^{-n}$$
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} 4^n \cdot z^{-n} $$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 4^{-n}\cdot z^{n} $$

As far as I know:
$$\frac{a_1}{1-r}=\frac {\frac{z}{4}}{1-\frac{z}{4}}=\frac{-1}{1-4 \cdot z^{-1}}$$

When it is in the $\frac{1}{1-a \cdot z^{-1}}$ form, I know how to check stability.

However, I am not sure how to find stability if there is a minus sign before the result.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let us first stablish somethings just by looking at the signal:

**1)** The $u[-n-1]$ step function indicates that the system has values $\neq 0$ only for negative values of $n$, what means it is **anticausal**.

**2)** If it is **anticausal**, then its $ROC$ looks like this: $|z|\lt r$

Having this in mind, we can follow up your steps to find the Z-tansform of the system:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{Z}\{h(n)\}=H(z)&= \sum_{k= -\infty}^\infty 4^k\cdot u[-k-1] \cdot z^{-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1} 4^k \cdot z^{-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 4^{-k}\cdot z^{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{z}{4}\right)^k
\end{align}
$$

Here we can confirm that the series converges for: $$|z|\lt 4$$

As you stated, this converges to the infite geometric progression sum:

$$\frac{a_{1}}{1-q}$$

Where, in our case we have: $a_{1}=q=\frac{z}{4}$, so:

$$
\begin{align}
H(z)&=\frac{\frac{z}{4}}{1-\frac{z}{4}}\\
&=\frac{z}{4-z}\\
&=\frac{1}{4z^{-1}-1}\\
&=-\frac{1}{1-4z^{-1}}
\end{align}
$$

This way, for this system we have: Zeros:$\{0\}$ and Poles:$\{4\}$

The unit circle $|z|=1$ is in the $ROC$ of this system, which is a fundamental requirement for stability, and, once $|z|\lt 4$ does not contain $4$, the poles are outside the $ROC$.

Therefore, this system is **stable**.

Regarding your doubt on how to treat the minus sign, it does not change the result about the poles, look:

$$
\begin{align}
1-4z^{-1}&=0 & 4z^{-1}-1&=0\\
4z^{-1}&=1 & 4z^{-1}&=1\\
z=&4 & z&=4
\end{align}
$$